# How to get timeStamp in java like this code in C#

Tags: java, c#

How can I re-write the code below (that is written in C#), in java to get same result?

```
TimeSpan Now = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970,1, 1));
long TimeStamp = Convert.ToInt64(Math.Floor(Now.TotalMilliseconds));
```

I want to translate the C# code to java language to get the value of TimeStamp (long variable).

Comment: If you are using java8, use LocalDateTime

Comment: I use LocalDateTime and get time between now and 1.1.1970 by period.between. but I want to convert this to TimeStamp (long variable) format  like c# code.@aviad

Comment: Is the above code just giving you the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970? I'm not a C# person. What would the output of your code look like in C#?

Comment: @ Michael Markidis yes. It gives a number like this : 1463568180761.

Comment: If you are always doing it from 1/1/1970, then you can use System.currentTimeMillis();

Comment: @Michael Markidis  Thank you. I think it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
 java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
  System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```